# Vue Js Input Field phone number

Tags: vue.js, input, vuejs2, numbers

So using Vue 2,
I would like to create an input field that restricts the data entered to a maximum of 10 numbers however I need for the first number to be from  1-9 and the rest of the numbers to be from 0-9.

so for example 0126372827 is not allowed because it starts with a 0 I need for the first number to not have a 0 is this possible ?

here is my current code:

```html
<input type="number" maxlength ="10"/>
```

Comment: Were you looking for input masking? Or just input validation?

Comment: Erm my bad I am looking for input masking

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the `input` element, bind the value to reactive data, and add a method to filter.

The caveat is you must also force update when denying the input value.  This will clear the invalid input and revert to the current data state.

```
<template>
  <input
    type="number"
    :value="validValue"
    @input="onInput($event.target.value)"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      validValue: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(value) {
      if (value === "") {
        this.validValue = value;
      } else if (value.length >= 10) {
        this.$forceUpdate();
      } else if (!/^[1-9][0-9]*$/.test(value)) {
        this.$forceUpdate();
      } else {
        this.validValue = value;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```